# Magento: Custom "Out of Stock" message not disabled with product becomes in stock

Tags: magento, product, stock, inventory

Default behavior:
When a product's quantity is 0 - the "out of stock" message is displayed. When the product becomes in stock (inventory updated by SAP), the "out of stock" message is disabled automatically.

Custom behavior:
However, when a "custom out of stock" message is selected and the product becomes in stock, for whatever reason, the "custom out of stock" message is NOT disabled. This has to be done explicitly on the product.

--

After searching for a solution, one option is to buy/install an extension that handles "out of stock" products, but has anyone found a way to tackle this internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the is_in_stock flag during your update as '1' if qty>0. If this is not possible with your code then you will need to select all of your products with stock greater than zero and set them to is_in_stock=1. You can run this as a standalone script with no performance disadvantage to writing a module and putting that module on a cron job that will chime in after your update has gone through. Here is the pseudocode:

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1));

foreach($stockCollection as $item) {
    $item->setIsInStock(1)->save();
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems logical. However, I was told that this should be the default behavior within magento and that the cache has to be cleared for the custom "out of stock" message to get disabled.